# Неявное приведение типов в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Возникли проблемы с пониманием приведения типов в C#. Я создал простой класс и перегрузил для него метод ToString(),чтобы выводились в строчку значения полей объекта класса:

```
public class Triple
{
    public int Int32;
    public string String;
    public bool Boolean;

    public Triple(int Int32, string String, bool Boolean)
    {
        this.Int32 = Int32;
        this.String = String;
        this.Boolean = Boolean;

    }
     public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", this.Int32, this.String, this.Boolean);
    }
```

Также я задал неявное приведения объекта класса Triple к типу bool:

```
 public static implicit operator bool(Triple T1)
    {

        return T1.Boolean;
    }
```

Теперь при вызове

```
Triple t1 = new Triple(1, "abcd", true);
Console.WriteLine(t1);
```

Выводится поле Boolean класса Triple,а не значение полей класса.Почему так происходит?Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Все просто дело все в приоритетах интерпретатор постарается привести сначала к стандартным типам если не сможет то вызовет ToString

Comment: `if (T1.Boolean) ...` замените на `return T1.Boolean;`, а то выглядит слишком жестко

Comment: @aepot `if (T1.Boolean == true) { return true; } else { return false; }` — ещё ж0ще.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данном случае у вас есть 2 конкурирующих перегрузки метода `Console.WriteLine`:

- `WriteLine(bool)` — принимает `bool`
- `WriteLine(object)` — принимает `object`

Ваш тип, а точнее, объект вашего типа, подходит под обе перегрузки:

- `implicit operator bool(Triple)` — подходит под 1-ю перегрузку
- Неявное наследование от `object` — подходит под 2-ю перегрузку

И что же выберет вам компилятор? В .NET действует 1 простое правило: «больше извращённость — больше приоритет».

В данном случае "извращённость" больше у неявного оператора upcast'а к `bool`, чем у наследования, т.к. `bool > object`.

Такая расстановка приоритетов связанна ещё с такими случаями:

```
public struct MyBoolean : IMyInterface
{
    readonly bool value;

    // реализация своего `bool`
}
```

Такой тип нужен только в 1-м случае: если вам нужен `bool`, реализующий какой-либо интерфейс, при этом это именно `bool`, а не объект с состоянием `bool`. Т.е. в `MyBoolean` перегрузка операторов и создание соответствующих `true`/`false` констант нужны, т.к. `MyBoolean` — это именно `bool`, но с интерфейсом. А вот уже условный `ManualResetEvent` — это другое; в нём единственное, фактически, состояние — 1 поле типа `bool`, но никто в нём не делает мер, которые были бы сделаны типу `MyBoolean`, т.к.

> Вы не понимаете — это другое!

И как вы думаете, что ожидает человек от такого кода:

```
var @bool = new MyBoolean(true);

Console.WriteLine(@bool);
```

Конечно же `True` в консоль, а не имя типа `MyBoolean` со всеми пространствами имён.